# Does a Bangladeshi citizen holding a multi-entry Indian visa need a transit visa for Nepal

Tags: visas, nepal, bhutan

I am a Bangladeshi citizen and have applied for multiple entry visa to India. Now I plan to visit India, Nepal & Bhutan all together. Do I need a transit visa for Nepal?

Answer (score 1):

You are already aware of the visa requirements for India. Here the results of a search on [IATA's Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=BD&NV=Bangladesh&DC=IN&DV=India&TC=BT%2CNP&TV=Bhutan%2CNepal&h=c7e5f692aae5425d6d9c5b5f6fe1b4d03a14d4), the database used by airlines to verify passenger visa and passport requirements (courtesy of Emirates):

> **Transit - Bhutan (BT)**
>
> **Visa**
>   Visa required.
>
> **Visa Exemptions:**
>   Nationals of Bangladesh for a maximum stay of 14 days.
>
> **Transit - Nepal (NP)**
>
> **Visa**
>   Visa required.
>
> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>   Holders of confirmed onward tickets transiting on the same calendar day.
>
> **Visa Issuance:**
>   Passengers with onward tickets can obtain a transit visa on arrival for a maximum of 24 hours.
>
> - This does not apply to nationals of Bangladesh traveling with a temporary passport, who must obtain a visa prior to travel.
>     This does not apply to nationals of Bangladesh traveling with a temporary passport, who must obtain a visa prior to travel.